# "Error starting ApplicationContext" when executing spring application

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I got few microservices and two are running great but on the other two I got some errors. The database schema is not created yet but usually it was created once I started the application successfully. I got similar running classes and I already tried few things such as deleting my repository in .m2 folder which didn't worked out.
I am also using eureka discovery service and eureka zuul.

I am not sure but I think it's not able to find the database schema. When I added a `@Entity` annotation in another but similar project it failed for the first time.

**UPDATE**

I figured out that I used the same coloumn name twice in a java class. So the first application is running again. But the second one (similar architecture) doesn't run when I am using annotations such as `@Entity` or `@Column`. When I delete them everything is working. The error message is the same.

**UPDATE 2**
I think it's a logical issue between the following two classes. I am two exhausted right now to figure out tho.

```
package de.leuphana.jee.component.structure;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class AddressEntity {

private Integer addressId;
private String city;
private String street;
private int zip;

public AddressEntity(String city, String street, int zip) 
{
    this.city = city;
    this.street = street;
    this.zip = zip;
}

public AddressEntity() {

}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Integer getAddressId() {
    return addressId;
}

@Column(name = "city")
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

@Column(name = "street")
public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

@Column(name = "zip")
public int getZip() {
    return zip;
}

public void setZip(int zip) {
    this.zip = zip;
}

}
```

---

```
package de.leuphana.jee.component.structure;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class OrderEntity {

private Set<AddressEntity> addresses;
private LocalDate orderDate;
private Integer orderId;
private Set<OrderItemEntity> orderItemsEntitySet;

public OrderEntity(AddressEntity addressEntity, LocalDate orderDate) {
    addresses = new HashSet<>();
    addresses.add(addressEntity);
    this.orderDate = orderDate;
    orderItemsEntitySet = new HashSet<>();
}

public OrderEntity() {

}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Integer getOrderId() {
    return orderId;
}

public void setOrderId(Integer orderId) {
    this.orderId = orderId;
}

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<OrderItemEntity> getOrderItemsEntitySet() {
    return orderItemsEntitySet;
}

public void setOrderItemsEntitySet(Set<OrderItemEntity> orderItemsEntitySet) 
{
    this.orderItemsEntitySet = orderItemsEntitySet;
}

public void addOrderItem(OrderItemEntity orderItemEntity) {
    orderItemsEntitySet.add(orderItemEntity);
}

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<AddressEntity> getAddresses() {
    return addresses;
}

public void setAddresses(Set<AddressEntity> addresses) {
    this.addresses = addresses;
}

public void addAddress(AddressEntity addressEntity) {
    addresses.add(addressEntity);
}
}
```

**OLD PROBLEM (pom.xml / application.properties are similar in every project)**

Java class:

```
package de.leuphana.jee.component.structure;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class CustomerEntity {
// intrinsic attribute
private Integer customerId;

// relational attribute
private CartEntity cartEntity;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Integer getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public CartEntity getCartEntity() {
    return cartEntity;
}

public void setCartEntity(CartEntity cartEntity) {
    this.cartEntity = cartEntity;
}

}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop
spring.datasource.username=shop
spring.datasource.password=shop
server.port=8082
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>customermicroservice</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <docker.image.prefix>microservice</docker.image.prefix>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Finchley.M8</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <finalName>app</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}
</repository>
                <buildArgs>

<JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                </buildArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- brauchen wir die repository? was macht die? -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

Full error message: (sorry for format)

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-03-18 10:14:41.918 ERROR 11928 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at de.leuphana.jee.Application.main(Application.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:895) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: de.leuphana.jee.component.structure.CartItemEntity column: article_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:835) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:853) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:875) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:607) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:459) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED THE ISSUE**

The issue wasn't logical, at least not the way I expected it. I had no setter method for `addressId`!
Feeling so stupid right now.
My code wasn't able to set a primary key for `AddressEntity`